# localhost apache2 page is not available

Tags: apache2, lamp, xampp

I have installed Apache2 on ubuntu via Ubuntu Software Center, but I have removed it, deleted its folders and files, and then, installed xampp for ubuntu, which worked. But then, I unistalled xampp and installed apache again, but I'm not able to see anything from the localhost. Every time I try to see, the browser shows "This webpage is not available" and the favicon shown is the xampp icon. How can I solve this??

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a index.html file into /var/www folder or what ever you have your virtual host directed to.